# Pulling data from squid proxy

Tags: squid

As the title says, I want to pull data from my proxy.

**Background:**
Recently I've got a surge in the amount of data that has to be saved, and the module I'm running at the moment just doesn't cut it*, it generates a html-file filled with styling and stuff (currently I've got more than 200% overhead, which isn't very fun when you've got a data retention plan on over 6 months and 30+ users).

**Problem:**
I want to pull as much data as possible from the proxy and insert it into a database (with minimum overhead, . This, I honestly don't know how to do (the pulling from proxy part. I don't need a `programming 101` *thank you very much*).

**Question:**
Any of these (whatever might be the more appropriate):

- Where does the statistics that `sarg` display come from (it displays *a lot* more than what's in the logfiles)?
- Are there any other source of statistics other than the logfiles (`/var/log/squid/access.log` | `cache.log`)?

`* sarg`

(Go ahead and flag it as "move to `SO`" if you think it's more appropriate there. I thought this question kinda in the grey, therefore I put it here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sarg takes all the data from the log files.

If you want to take more information, have a look at the [Cache Manager](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/CacheManager). It has internal information about Squid.

Squid can be configured to send the logs via UDP. I wrote an [script](https://github.com/diegows/xreport/blob/master/squid/tools/squid-access.py) that takes information UDP and loads it to a database. It's based in a Turbogears 2 project, but may be it's helpful for you to start.